# Flasks blueprint not finding templates or static in root directory

Tags: python, flask

I'm in the midst of refactoring my flask app to use blueprints, and I can't seem to get the blueprint to find the templates or static directories in the app's root directory. The templates/static files are recognised only when I put their folders in the blueprint's directory, which would be fine if the files were used only by that specific blueprint, however I need other modules to be able to access them too (for example the base.html template). I've tried setting the templates & static folder location in the blueprint set up ie.

```
bp = Blueprint('main', __name__,
           template_folder='templates',
           static_folder='static')
```

as well as leaving it blank (in an attempt to get it to default to looking in the root directory)

```
bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)
```

I've also tried putting in the path explicitly ie.

```
template_folder='app/templates'
```

to no avail.

My app directory looks like this (replaced my names with generic directory names and omitted the other modules as I'm trying to just get this one working first):

```
library root/
   __init__.py
   setup.py
   app/
      venv/
      templates/
         base.html
         home.html
      static/
         css,js & img files
      blueprint/
         __init__.py
```

The library root `(app)/__init__.py`
 looks like this

```
import os

from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

def init(app):
    #config init...

    from app.main import bp as main_bp

    app.register_blueprint(main_bp)
    print (app.url_map)

init(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init(app)

    app.run(
        host=app.config['ip_address'],
        port=int(app.config['port']))
```

And the `blueprint/__init__.py` looks like this:

```
from flask import Blueprint

# Set up a Blueprint
bp = Blueprint('main', __name__,
               template_folder='templates',
               static_folder='static')

#without setting the template & static locations
#bp = Blueprint('main', __name__)

from flask import render_template


@bp.route('/')
def root():
    return render_template('home.html'), 200
```

My `app.url_map` output looks like this:

```
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> static>])
Map([<Rule '/' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> main.root>,
 <Rule '/' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> main.root>,
 <Rule '/static/<filename>' (HEAD, GET, OPTIONS) -> static>])
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? As far as I was able to see in the various blueprint tutorials around, the default place the app will look for the templates folder is the root directory, followed by the blueprint directory, so why isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**init**.py should be under app directory, move it from library root to app directory to solve this issue.

Comment: As I said, I tried that too (see my second code snippet); it doesn't work.

Comment: ok, create new file route.py in blueprint directory and move code from __init__.py to route.py , keey  __init__.py empty.

Comment: __init__.py should be inside app directory , i can see this is in library root, try moving it in app

Comment: Ah excellent, that did it! For some reason PyCharm kept creating new __init__.py files in the root directory. Thank you!

Comment: thanks for confirmation, updated the answer as per last comment.